# an action hook when a post reaches a certain number of views

Tags: filters, hooks, publish, views

I am using  [WP Post Views](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin to display the post number of views. I use:

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?>
```

I am creating a badge system for my wordpress site. My actual goal is to create a badge for number of post views: If a post has a number of views exceeding a certain threshold, then the author is awarded this badge.

How can I achieve this using action hooks? Till now, all the badges I have created use the priciple of action hooks (For instance, the badge related to the number of an author published posts uses post_publish action hook). Should I look for another approch for the views badge other than hooks?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the WP Post Views plugin that you're using have any functions that `return` a post's view count?  If so, you should be able to award the badge based on that number. (I'd suggest adding the badge(s) to the user's meta information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the action from `update_post_meta()`:

```
do_action( 
    "updated_{$meta_type}_meta", // example: updated_post_meta
    $meta_id, 
    $object_id, // post ID
    $meta_key, // 'view'
    $_meta_value // view count
);
```

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
add_action( 'update_post_meta', 'badge_check', 10, 4 );

function badge_check( $meta_id, $post_id, $key, $value )
{
    if ( 'views' !== $key or 1000 > $value )
        return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! $user->ID )
        return;

    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'badge', 'Kilo viewer' );
}
```

Comment: thank you @toscho. It is the starting point for a big knowledge I am running through. In fact your answer guided me to many other SE topics that I am trying to understand now. I will be back here to edit and accept your answer when correctly implemented. Have a good day.

Comment: please what do 10 and 4 refer to?? thank you

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces `10` is the priority and `4` the number of accepted arguments.